# extract data from a xml file to Excel or a txt file

Tags: excel, extract

I want to figure out how I can pull data from the a record in an xml and out put that information into a excel or just a text file with proper separation so I can easily copy it. Below is a sample of a record and I simply want to get the information from ITEM_NO, DESCRIPTION, CATEGORY, CLASSIFICATION, LIST_RATE.

```
 <Record>
<ITEM_NO> 049000045734</ITEM_NO>
<ITEM_MANU>0</ITEM_MANU>
<LOCATION>2</LOCATION>
<DESCRIPTION>Powerade Lemon 32 Oz</DESCRIPTION>
<CATEGORY>ED</CATEGORY>
<CLASSIFICATION>Non-Alcoholic Drink</CLASSIFICATION>
<SUB_CATEGORY></SUB_CATEGORY>
<PLACEMENT>1</PLACEMENT>
<DEPARTMENT>0</DEPARTMENT>
<REV_ACCT>200</REV_ACCT>
<ISSU_UNT_CST>0</ISSU_UNT_CST>
<ISSU_UNT_MEA>EA</ISSU_UNT_MEA>
 <PRICING>
 <LIST_TYPE>F</LIST_TYPE>
 <LIST_RATE>3.5</LIST_RATE>
 <LIST_TOGO>0</LIST_TOGO>
 <LIST_TOGOA>0</LIST_TOGOA>
 <LIST_ROOM>0</LIST_ROOM>
 <LIST_ROOMA>0</LIST_ROOMA>
 <LIST_BAR>0</LIST_BAR>
 <LIST_BARA>0</LIST_BARA>
 <LIST_CHILD>0</LIST_CHILD>
 <LIST_TEENS>0</LIST_TEENS>
 <LIST_SENIOR>0</LIST_SENIOR>
  <TAXES>
  <TAXRATE1>0</TAXRATE1>
  <TAXRATE2>0</TAXRATE2>
  <TAXRATE3>0</TAXRATE3>
  <PUR_UNT_MEA>EA</PUR_UNT_MEA>
  <PUR_UNT_CST>0</PUR_UNT_CST>
  <CNV_UM>1</CNV_UM>
  <REORDER_PT>0</REORDER_PT>
  <REORDER_QTY>0</REORDER_QTY>
  <STD_COST>0</STD_COST>
  <LEAD_TIME>0</LEAD_TIME>
  <QTY_ONHAND>-14</QTY_ONHAND>
  <QTY_ONORDER>0</QTY_ONORDER>
  <QTY_INSTOCK>0</QTY_INSTOCK>
  <LAST_SALE_DT>79636</LAST_SALE_DT>
  <ITEMSTATUS>A</ITEMSTATUS>
  <DISPLAYICON></DISPLAYICON>
  <TIMESSELECTED></TIMESSELECTED>
  <OVERRIDEGROUP1>0</OVERRIDEGROUP1>
  <OVERRIDEGROUP2>0</OVERRIDEGROUP2>
  <OVERRIDEGROUP3>0</OVERRIDEGROUP3>
  <OVERRIDEGROUP4>0</OVERRIDEGROUP4>
  <OVERRIDEGROUP5>0</OVERRIDEGROUP5>
  <OVERRIDEGROUP6>0</OVERRIDEGROUP6>
  <OVERRIDEGROUP7>0</OVERRIDEGROUP7>
  <OVERAMTGROUP1>0</OVERAMTGROUP1>
  <OVERAMTGROUP2>0</OVERAMTGROUP2>
  <OVERAMTGROUP3>0</OVERAMTGROUP3>
  <OVERAMTGROUP4>0</OVERAMTGROUP4>
  <OVERAMTGROUP5>0</OVERAMTGROUP5>
  <OVERAMTGROUP6>0</OVERAMTGROUP6>
  <OVERAMTGROUP7>0</OVERAMTGROUP7>
  <ORIDEPRINTER>0</ORIDEPRINTER>
  <EIGHTYSIX>0</EIGHTYSIX>
  <COUNTDOWN>0</COUNTDOWN>
  <ADDTIPLINE>0</ADDTIPLINE>
  <EXT_DESC></EXT_DESC>
  </TAXES>
 </PRICING>
</Record>
```

Comment: What research have you done? Where are you stuck with coding this? Please take the [tour] and see [ask] and [mcve] help resources for guidance on posting questions on this site.

Comment: I'm not really good at coding, I figure someone has to know a way I can do this with out me sorting through over a thousand records and typing it out manually.

Comment: Hi, I understand. The idea of this site is not that we write all the code for you but that we help you with your attempt. Researching will help you understand both the code you write and any solutions given. There are lots of examples on StackOverflow of reading xml documents using xml parsers and extracting info from nodes, for example, using xpath. You can also likely use html parsers and grab by tag.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+xml

Comment: If you have access program, You can import an xml file from external data import and export it as a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access program, You can import an xml file from external data import and export it as a Excel file or a text file.

Access  import xml
[image]

export Excel

[image]

Comment: Thank You, This will really speed up my process